# How to make Spring JPA + Hibernate and Native Query compatible with multi database?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, postgresql, hibernate

Does anyone have experience with **Spring JPA + Hibernate** so that the Native Query can adapt to the database we are using? (Compatible with multi database)

For example, if we connect to PostgreSQL we will use **query A**, if we connect to MySQL we will use **query B**.

Is the solution is to create 2 or more different Repositories?
or is there a more elegant solution?

*First note*, because Native Query PostgreSQL is different from Native Query MySQL.

*Second note*, I want to make software that the user will be able to choose what database they want to use, as long as it is supported by hibernate. So user just need to change the configuration file.

Thank you

Comment: That is what JPQL is meant for. A Native query is, as the name already implies, native for the choosen database.

Comment: yes, that right. but some time JPQL can't achieve what our goal. sometime we need a complex query. But thank you for your response, i will explore about JPQL more.

Comment: The only solution is to write the native queries for all the databases you (want to) support. Or stop using JPA/Hibernate and use something like JOOQ